# Gradle: Not able to run zipTree in doFirst block

Tags: gradle, configuration, dependencies

I am trying to explode some jar files in a doFirst block as follows -

```
task copyBinaries(type: Copy){

    def Jar1 = ""
    def Jar2 = ""
    def Jar3 = ""
    doFirst {
        Jar1 = configurations.Lib1.singleFile
        Jar2 = configurations.Lib2.singleFile
        Jar3 = configurations.Lib3.singleFile   
    }

    inputs.files configurations.Lib1
    inputs.files configurations.Lib2
    inputs.files configurations.Lib3

    from(zipTree(file(Jar1))) {
            into('jar_folder1')
    }
    from(zipTree(file(Jar2))) {
            into('jar_folder2')
    }
    from(zipTree(file(Jar3))) {
            into('jar_folder3')
    }
    into('build/libs/')
    }
}
```

In order the avoid resolution of dependencies in the configuration phase, I am extracting the file names from the configurations in the doFirst block. The problem is, since the Copy task needs the source and destination of copy during configuration phase, gradle sees Jar1, Jar2, Jar3 as empty strings and throws and error. 
I am looking for a way to let the Copy task receive arguments (source file) during execution phase (after doFirst block is executed).

How can I address this situation? Thanks.

Comment: Maybe something using https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/file/CopySpec.html ?

Answer (score 1):

I've had a similar situation where I had to copy from a path that was created as output of another one.
I solved this with just declaring the copy logic in my task's doLast block:

```
task copyStuff {
    doLast {
        copy {
            from zipTree('path/to/archive')
            into 'destination/dir'
        }
    }
}
```

You just have to make sure, that your task runs after the task that creates the needed outputs with using dependsOn for example.